# Как сделать так, чтобы только первая строка списка была красной?

Tags: html, css

Сейчас нахождение в `<li></li>` создаёт отступ для всего содержимого. Как сделать так, чтобы отступ был только для первой строки, как в книгах?

[image: Новая строка списка не имеет отступа]

Answer (score 2):

Для решения достаточно установить свойство [`list-style-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) в значение `inside`.

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<h1>10 книжных фактов</h1>
<ol>
  <li>Все, что я пытаюсь сделать, это выжить и извлечь пользу из грязного, отвратительного, невероятного образа жизни, который они мне дали</li>
  <li>Каждый раз, когда вы поднимаетесь, что-то случается, что заставляет вас вернуться обратно</li>
  <li>Моя мама всегда говорила мне: «Если ты не можешь найти, ради чего жить, тебе лучше найти то, ради чего можно умереть</li>
  <li>Факт</li>
  <li>Факт</li>
  <li>Факт</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Для наглядности я бы выставил ширину для `ol`, а так отличный ответ! Плюсик дам.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, да в принципе длинные строки и так не влезают

Comment: Оу.. Ну возможно.. я просто расширял немного сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Если список будет не вложенный, можно обойтись через [counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters).
Для красной первой строки можно воспользоваться [::first-line](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp), прошу заметить, для него не сработает `padding` и `margin`.

```css
ol { width: 300px; padding: 0; list-style: none; counter-reset: counter; }

li
{
  counter-increment: counter;
}

li::before
{
  color: initial; /* убрать это, если нужно красить цифру тоже в красный */
  content: counter(counter) ")";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Делаем первую строку красной */
li::first-line
{
  color: #DC4242;
}
```

```html
<h1>10 книжных фактов</h1>
<ol>
  <li>Все, что я пытаюсь сделать, это выжить и извлечь пользу из грязного, отвратительного, невероятного образа жизни, который они мне дали</li>
  <li>Каждый раз, когда вы поднимаетесь, что-то случается, что заставляет вас вернуться обратно</li>
  <li>Моя мама всегда говорила мне: «Если ты не можешь найти, ради чего жить, тебе лучше найти то, ради чего можно умереть</li>
  <li>Факт</li>
  <li>Факт</li>
  <li>Факт</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Кхм.. Кажись я подумал не о том, мне нужны уточнения)